# Tkinter Entry Input Non ASCII Character Turn to "?" Python 3.6.4

Tags: python, tkinter, encode, utf

This is my code
If I try to input by the keyboard some Vietnamese Characters like "ạ" or "ả" it turns to "?". But if it is "à" then it's still okay
for example: "aàáảãạ" -> "aàá?ã?"
But if I type "aàáảãạ" somewhere else then copy to the entry box, it works perfectly.

```
def __init__(self, master):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.master = master
    self.master.title("Login HR")
    #self.master.geometry("400x300")
    Label(master, text="Username: ").grid(row=0)
    Label(master, text="Password: ").grid(row=1)
    self.e1 = Entry(master,font=("Times New Roman", 10))
    self.e2 = Entry(master,font=("Times New Roman", 10))
    self.e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
    self.e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
    Button(master, text='Quit', command=self.master.quit).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
    Button(master, text='Login', command=self.userLogin).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)
```

Comment: the font you are using is likely missing that codepoint ... you will probably have to specify the font you wish to use (that has all the characters you need)

Comment: I already try: 
self.e1 = Entry(master,font=("Times New Roman", 10))
self.e2 = Entry(master,font=("Times New Roman", 10))
But nothing change. <And I'm sure that Times has full Vietnamese Characters Set.>

Comment: I recommend you try another font, just to rule out an issue with the font. It should take you just a minute or two.

Comment: I tried Arial then but it doesn't solve the problem. For more detail, if I type "aàáảãạ" somewhere else then copy to the entry box, it works perfectly.